# Why doesn't Vue 3 remove template comments from DOM in production?

Tags: vue.js

According to Vue [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-compileroptions-comments), it should remove HTML comments when building for production.

However, for me that's not the case. All `<!-- comments -->` are still visible in DOM through devtools in production. Has anyone faced it ever?

Explicitly setting `app.config.compilerOptions.comments = false` didn't help either

Comment: Are those comments empty? something like `<!--[-->`. It also depends on what tooling you're using and how it is configured.

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero not empty. all the commented text is preserved

Comment: Could you share what tooling (Vite, Webpack, Parcel, etc) are you using and how is configured?

Comment: only vue-cli with minimal config

Comment: How are you building your prod distribution? Are you running `vue-cli-service build --mode production` ? Worth checking if the mode is not being overridden via local ENV vars as per https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables